# Get list of iOS keyboard emoji programmatically

Tags: ios, emoji

Is there a way to get a list of all emoji unicode characters on iOS keyboard programmatically?

Cheers

[image]

Comment: Did you get solution for this?

Comment: @iOS_Binod nopes, for now I've had to manually copy emojis from ios keyboard